# Only the '/' works with NGINX ingress controller and ALB in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks

I created an EKS cluster and deployed an NGINX ingress controller with an Application load balancer. I deployed a sample app and tied it to my domain name.
Here is the ingress file -

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "2048-ingress"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
  labels:
    app: 2048-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test.abc.xyz
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /game
            backend:
              serviceName: "service-2048"
              servicePort: 80
```

When I open test.abc.xyz/game in my browser it returns a 404 but test.abc.xyz works. Am I missing something here? I want test.abc.xyz/game to work and test.abc.xyz to return a 404.

Update - 
I am following this tutorial to deploy the app - 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/kubernetes-ingress-aws-alb-ingress-controller/
I want this app to be redirected to /game and not /

Comment: can you share the output of kubectl describe ing 2048-ingress

Comment: share the alb rules that you have defined. Also, check does your service responds on /game you might have something after that.

Comment: Describe ingress returns an error. Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource. I can only do a get or an edit which is strange. Here is the ALB rule. 
IF
Path is /game THEN forward to the TARGET GROUP

Comment: This [aws tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html)  can be helpful

Comment: I tried it. The basic configuration works but it doesn't work for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: `"Describe ingress returns an error. Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource. I can only do a get or an edit which is strange. Here is the ALB rule. IF Path is /game THEN forward to the TARGET GROUP"`


This doesn't sound good, I would try removing and recreating the ingress to see if the problem persists, or succeeds, and whether you can get more info if it still fails.

Depending on how that goes, I would then check the health of the `service-2048` service; specifically that it's healthy and configured to listen on port 80.

Comment: The describe ingress is a know issue - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/675. Regarding if the service is listening - Yes it is listening. I can do a port-forward and it works. Only the mapping is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define an wildcard in the path section like below:

```
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test.abc.xyz
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: "service-2048"
              servicePort: 80
   - path: /game/*
            backend:
              serviceName: "service-2048"
              servicePort: 80
```

Unfortunately is not well written in the documentation.